# R: Convert text (character) into integer type in a data frame

Tags: r, text, dataframe, integer, read.csv

I'm now working on an input data frame :

```
Asset   Sector        Currency    MarketValue
 1       Financial       USD         100000
 2       Financial       USD         100000
...
100      Financial       USD         100000
```

While now I want to add a row to the data frame but with different sector:

```
101       Energy         USD         100000
```

I'm now trying the code:

```
newSector        <- rep(input[95,])
newSector$Sector <- "Energy"
input            <- rbind(input,newSector)
```

However, from the `read.csv2()` the sector column is read as integer type, while `newSector$Sector <- "Energy"` is just to change the cell to a character type "Energy", therefore I'm not able to `rbind` them together. R reports the error: "invalid factor level, NA generated".

I tried to do `strtoi` and `as.integer` but it reported "NAs introduced by coercion".

Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are introducing new levels the incorrect way. Try `levels(input$Sector) = c(levels(input$Sector), "Energy")` first. Are you sure you that even need factors here?

Comment: Hi pierre, thank you for telling me this method. It works with `rbind` the new row, but then I find that I shouldn't just do `rep` with the new row, cuz it keeps the value of "Financial" but just change the name into "Energy", which will not match my calculations later using correlation matrix of "Financial" and "Energy". I used @Uwe Block 's method and it leaded me to the result I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `read.csv2` implies the parameter `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. Therefore, column `Sector` and all other character data are coerced to factor where the factor levels are given by integer numbers.

Please, try to read the input file again with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

For appending an additional sector, please, try something along

```
newsector <- data.frame(Asset = 101, Sector = "Energy", 
                        Currency = "USD", MarketValue = 100000, 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
input <- rbind(input, newSector)
```

Note the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is required here again to prevent coersion to factor.

Comment: Thank you Uwe! I didn't change the `read.csv2` setting because in other files people are also using it. I set the `newsector <- data.frame(,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)` and it works well to get my final result. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like `read.csv()` is reading the Sector column is as a factor rather than an integer (or a character string, which is what you expect). R stores factors as integers under the covers which is why you're getting the `invalid factor level, NA generated` error.

You can confirm this by doing `str(input)` and looking at the classes of each column.

A couple possible solutions:

1. use the `stringsAsFactors=F` argument when you use `read.csv()` to read in your original file. That way the Sector column comes in a a character column and you don't get confused (you can always convert Sector back to a factor later if you need that for your analysis.
2. convert the existing input$Sector to a character column:

   ```
   input$Sector  <- as.character(input$Sector)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is called `df` you can try adding the row this way:

```
df[101,] <- c(101, "Energy", "USD", 100000)
```

The vector contains character and numeric values but since R cannot have vectors of multiple classes it will default to character. Adding this character vector will convert all 4 of your columns to character. You can change the columns intended to be integer using `lapply`:

```
df[c(1,4)] <- lapply(df[c(1,4)], as.integer)
```

**Edit**: This will not work if the second column is a factor and the value being added isn't one of the levels as is the case in this example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Asset=1:5,
  Sector=rep("Financial", 5),
  Currency=rep("USD",5),
  MarketValue=rep(100000,5)
)

> df[6,] <- c(101, "Energy", "USD", 100000)
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "Energy") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
  Asset    Sector Currency MarketValue
1     1 Financial      USD       1e+05
2     2 Financial      USD       1e+05
3     3 Financial      USD       1e+05
4     4 Financial      USD       1e+05
5     5 Financial      USD       1e+05
6   101      <NA>      USD       1e+05
```

This will work if `Sector` is converted to `character`

```
> df$Sector <- as.character(df$Sector)
> 
> df[6,] <- c(101, "Energy", "USD", 100000)
> df
  Asset    Sector Currency MarketValue
1     1 Financial      USD       1e+05
2     2 Financial      USD       1e+05
3     3 Financial      USD       1e+05
4     4 Financial      USD       1e+05
5     5 Financial      USD       1e+05
6   101    Energy      USD       1e+05
```

Notice the classes:

```
> sapply(df, class)
      Asset      Sector    Currency MarketValue 
"character" "character"    "factor" "character"
```

Now with `lapply` :

```
> df[c(1,4)] <- lapply(df[c(1,4)], as.integer)
> sapply(df, class)
      Asset      Sector    Currency MarketValue 
  "integer" "character"    "factor"   "integer"
```

Unless you have  specific need for factors in your data I recommend using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you `read.csv` as mentioned by other answers.

Comment: Have you tested this? You cannot escape factor level definition this way.